# React admin ResourceContextProvider is not injecting feteched Data in List component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I seriously need some help with react admin  ResourceContextProvider and List components. It took all my weekend and style don't have something which works :(. I was very exited with the new possiblity which came with the last react admin realease about  ResourceContextProvider and List components. unfortunatly it's not working for me.
ResourceContextProvider was supposed to help displaying the List component everywhere.

So my code is :

I Defined a custom route in order to redirect to my List like this :

```js
export default [
    
        <Route
            path="/api/camp/getListEtiq/:id/non_charge"
            
            render={(routeProps) =>  <ListEtiquette id={routeProps.match.params.id}  {...routeProps} />}
        />  
];
```

And my List of etiquettes is defined like this :

```js
const ListEtiquette = (props) => {
    const path = 'camp/getListEtiq/' + props.id + '/non_charge';
    const basePath = '/' + path;

    return (

        <ResourceContextProvider value={path} >
            <List syncWithLocation basePath={basePath} title="Liste des colis">
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <TextField source="numCodeEtiq" />
                </Datagrid>
            </List>
        </ResourceContextProvider>

    );

}

export default ListEtiquette;
```

My data provider getList is :

```js
    getList: (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            ...fetchUtils.flattenObject(params.filter),
            _sort: field,
            _order: order,
            _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
            _end: page * perPage,
            _resource:resource
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

        return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => {
            
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty('totalElements')) {
                throw new Error(
                  "The numberOfElements property must be must be present in the Json response"
                );
            }
            console.log(json.content);
            return {
                data: json.content,
                total: parseInt(json.totalElements,10)
            };
        });
    }
```

As resulat when i redirect to this page, the data is fetched :

```js
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "numCodeEtiq": "1/6-CG001"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "numCodeEtiq": "2/6-CG001"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "numCodeEtiq": "3/6-CG001"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "numCodeEtiq": "4/6-CG001"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "numCodeEtiq": "5/6-CG001"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "numCodeEtiq": "6/6-CG001"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "numCodeEtiq": "1/2-CG002"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "numCodeEtiq": "2/2-CG002"
        }
    ],
    "totalElements": 8
}
```

But list elements are not displayed  !!, data is not injected in the List component. (see how list is diplayed in the link below).

[React admin List component is not displaying list élementts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEAsN.png)

Whene i click on export button the data is exported :

[The data which is expored when i click on export button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAgnS.png)

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

React admin version : 3.12.1

React admin ref :  https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html

Comment: Did you try using ListBase?
I know it’s not the same but it seems to be working better for me. When I use List I get a number of react errors saying it’s missing props hasCreate, hasEdit, hasList, hasShow.

Comment: @JeremyRichardson I have tried, followed your update on github as well, doesn't work even with latest version. You have to add <Resource /> component to make it work

Comment: @Kumar Just to confirm, you do have a <Resource /> as a child of <Admin /> correct? According to docs, "You must add a <Resource> when you declare a reference (via <ReferenceField>, <ReferenceArrayField>, <ReferenceManyField>, <ReferenceInput> or <ReferenceArrayInput>), because react-admin uses resources to define the data store structure. That’s why there is an empty tag resource in the example above." I would assume this applies to ResourceContextProvider as well but not certain. It's odd though that the network request is made successfully though. Have you tried without syncWithLocation?

Comment: Been there done that @JeremyRichardson. For more info check this https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/6107

Comment: I'm curious to the response in the GitHub issue. Aren't you already providing the resource via the ResourceContextProvider in the example above?

Comment: @JeremyRichardson related to your message about error "List I get a number of react errors saying it’s missing props hasCreate, hasEdit, hasList, hasShow." I catched the same error, it comes from "pagination" property of "List" cos "<Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]} {...props} />" receive incorrect props, it shoult be outside of the component where is List located with his prop like this: <List  {...props} pagination={<PostPagination />}>...</List> and outside pagination component const PostPagination = (props) => (
 <Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[ 5, 10, 20]} {...props} />
);